# Form of a function I can fit like a polynomial that has an asymptote on x-axis and is always positive

Tags: polynomials, mathematical-modeling, data-analysis

So I have a small list of pairs of the form $(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0})$ and I want to fit a function to this data. Additionally I know that as $x$ grows large in either direction $y$ tends to zero (in fact I know that $y$ approaches zero at $\infty$ and $-\infty$). Additionally $y$ never approaches $\infty$ There may be many peaks in the middle as well. More generally I actually need to be able to fit data of the form $(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0})$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$. It should be noted that I am using a program to to fit the function so this need not be easy to do by hand. My first thought was to use a polynomial but polynomials do not tend to zero. My next thought was a rational function with a denominator larger than denominator but then there will be many vertical asymptotes giving values of y that approach $\infty$.

Do you know of such a form of a function that meets the above requirements (y never approaches infinity, y approaches zero at extreme, y is always positive, the function may have many peaks) that I can fit the constants of? (you may assume that I can fit any constants no matter what).

edit:
To be clear here are the requirements formally stated of $f(x)$ (a function which could model data)

1. $lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x)=0$
2. $lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}f(x)=0$
3. $\frac{d}{dx}(f(x)) = 0$ should have more than one solution
4. $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}. f(x) \ge 0$
5. $\forall a\in \mathbb{R}. lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x) \ne \infty$
6. The function should have unspecified constants that I can fit to my data
7. It is allowed that there be some requirements on the allowed values of the constants

Comment: How nice do you want your function to be? If you want it to be continuous (and total), then no such function exists.

Comment: I was hoping for continuous and total but I could give up totality ("total" meaning all inputs map to an output right? opposite of partial) as long as I could somehow fill in the gaps though some sort of averaging or interpolation

Comment: I might also be willing to give up continuity as long as it was because of pretty minor jumps

Comment: Any function that satisfies all the properties you want is liable to be highly discontinuous. For instance $f(x) = 1/x^2$ of $x$ is irrational and 0 otherwise works but it is discontinuous everywhere.

Comment: why is that discontinuous everywhere? I thought it was only discontinuous at 0. Also it approaches $\infty$ at zero which is not good.

Comment: What is there if I give continuity up? what happens if I give totalality up?

Comment: This is why you need to make your question precise. $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x) \neq \infty$ which is what I assumed you meant: In mathematics "approach" tends to mean taking limits. Notice that the function is only $1/x^2$ when $x$ is irrational. It is $0$ when $x$ is rational, and hence discontinuous everywhere.

If you give up your assumptions you can get all manner of different things, like the example I gave above.

Comment: I did mean limits when I said approaches. I'm having a hard to seeing what you mean about 1/x^2. If I plug in $1/2$ to $1/x^2$ I get $4$ which is not 0 even though $1/2$ is rational. I'm not sure we are even close to the same page here. 1/x^2 a) has no constants to fit and b) is a horibale way to model almost any data. It violates the idea that none of my data approaches infinity at any $x$. When I say "as x grows large in either direction y tends to zero" that means $lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}f(x)=0$ and $lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty}f(x)=0$. I don't think I stated that incorrectly

Comment: The function is NOT $1/x^2$ is is defined piecewise.

All I was doing was trying to show you that examples of functions that satisfy the data you want are quite pathological: There may not be any that does what you want.

Comment: 1/x^2 does not meet my requirements. It is also as far as I can see continuous except at 0. Additionally I am explicitly asking for functions that have constants I can fit to data